# Converting Valgrind XML Output to HTML

Tags: html, xml, converters, valgrind

I know there is a possibility to create a valgrind output in xml. But is there a possibility to convert it into html? Cause standard converter has problems with valgrind output convention. Or does anybody have a stylesheet for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Valgrind doesn't directly output as HTML, however there was talk on the [Valgrind Users](http://valgrind.10908.n7.nabble.com/Valgrind-report-in-html-td34775.html) mailing list about 10 years ago about developing a XSLT, however the links in the mailing list appear to be dead - or at least redirected.

There is also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28211610/valgrind-sample-output-report) which suggests there are other people working on such a thing.

Other than that if google can not find one for you, you will probably have to write your own, if you genuinely need one. But it might be just as easy to grab the standard output and insert that into an html page as go to the hassle of translating the xml.

In addition, ensure you are using the [correct options](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html), such as `--child-silent-after-fork=yes`

> Use of this option is also strongly recommended if you are requesting
>   XML output (--xml=yes), since otherwise the XML from child and parent
>   may become mixed up, which usually makes it useless.